# Firebird Data Acess using t4

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, 64-bit, firebird, t4

I am working to make data access layer using t4 template for Firebird Database (Embeded)

I am working on 64 bit system. Compile/Debug options AnyCPU (Windows 7 64bit) Visual studio 2010

I write the code in C# environment and test it, Its working fine with firebird.client , fembed .

But when I put the same code in t4 template and execute i get the following error message.

> Blockquote
>   Error 1   Running transformation: System.BadImageFormatException: An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)    at
>   FB_965910463_Class.isc_attach_database(IntPtr[] statusVector, Int16
>   dbNameLength, Byte[] dbName, Int32& dbHandle, Int16 parmBufferLength,
>   Byte[] parmBuffer)    at
>   FB_965910463_Class.IFbClient.isc_attach_database(IntPtr[]
>   statusVector, Int16 dbNameLength, Byte[] dbName, Int32& dbHandle,
>   Int16 parmBufferLength, Byte[] parmBuffer)    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Native.FesDatabase.Attach(DatabaseParameterBuffer
>   dpb, String dataSource, Int32 port, String database)    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()    at
>   FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating764D7C202C1B21D2B3446E16766F889E.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadTables()
>   in
>   c:\Users\waqarhabib\Desktop\FireBirdORM\FireBirdORM\FireBirdGen.ttinclude:line
>   132    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating764D7C202C1B21D2B3446E16766F889E.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   in c:\Users\waqarhabib\Desktop\FireBirdORM\FireBirdORM\DTO.tt:line 10 
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession
>   session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String&
>   result)       1   1

Comment: Could you try forcing your build to 64-bits instead of AnyCpu? I'm guessing if the T4 transformer is somehow running in 32-bits, and therefore not binding to the right non managed database client dll. Also make sure that the firebird's client dll's are built for 64-bits environment.

Comment: I tried change target platform to 64 bit but still having the same error? Same version of my t4 template for sql server on 64 bit is working fine

Comment: VS runs as 32bit IIRC on a 64bit system regardless. If the assemblies requires 64bit you would get the above error. If you try compiling your test application with to 32bit only and execute them I guess the error would reproduce?

Comment: I tried, when I set all of configuration to 32 bit sample application is working , but not the t4. behaviour and error is same either application is in 64bit or 32 bit. T4 template was tested on 32 bit system and working fine.

Comment: This is most likely caused by the FB ADO.NET client trying to load a 64-bit assembly or DLL. Project build configuration will have no effect. Try to get a successful connection from the Server Explorer in Visual Studio, then use the exact same connection string in your T4 template.

Comment: Dear Oleg Sych, I test same solution on another system with same installation (64/32) bit as my system. And it is working on that system. I have firebird and maestro installed I uninstall it. still getting the same problem. As of fb ado.net client I have a sample window application with same connection string and fbclient as my t4 template. the windows application working fine. the problem is when I execute/save t4 template i get the above error. trying from yesterday but still not succedde

Comment: Given the error message I guess it is trying to load the native/embedded library and you have the 32 bit embedded library, while it is expecting the 64 bit library, this seems to be confirmed because it does work when you set it to 32 bit config.

Comment: change the development scenario. As I tried but find no solution to develop it purely through t4 template. I used pre process t4 template and integrate it with C# classes.